# Update content when fancybox already open

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I call fancybox 2 on afterLoad event every time after $.post method

```
$.post ... function(html){
$.fancybox({afterLoad:function(){this.content = html;}});
}
```

It works fine when Fancybox is closed, but when I make this request one more time from already opened Fancybox I get error "Content cannot be loaded"!

I've trued beforeLoad, beforeShow and some other events, but no luck. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Don't you just want to do something like this?

```
$.post ... function(html){
    $.fancybox( html );
}
```

Comment: even this method closes old fancybox and opens new, not updating current fancybox, that works for me! thank you!

Comment: This does not open the new html content in the already opened fancybox, but first closes the one opened and then opens a new one.

Comment: If you add `openEffect : 'none'` the user will not notice that new fancybox popup was created.

Answer (score 2):

To load new content into an **already opened** fancybox, you can do the following. This way, the fancybox will **not close** in between updating the fancybox window with the new content:

```
// is fancybox already popped up?
fancyboxIsOpen: false,

openFancyBox: function (urlToBeLoaded) {
    if (urlToBeLoaded === null) {
        this.closeFancyBox();
    } else {
        if (this.fancyboxIsOpen) {
            this.openInAlreadyOpenedFancyBox(urlToBeLoaded);
        } else {
            this.openFirstFancyBox(urlToBeLoaded);                
        }
    } 
}, 

openFirstFancyBox: function (urlToBeLoaded) {
    var that = this;
    $.fancybox.open({
        type: 'ajax',
        href: urlToBeLoaded,
        afterClose: function() {
            this.openFancyBox(null);
            return true;
        },
        afterShow : function() {
            that.fancyboxIsOpen = true;
            var ahref = jQuery(".fancybox");
            ahref.on("click", function(event){
                //stop the click action, we do not want to load the href in the window
                event.preventDefault();         
                var currentTarget = $(event.currentTarget);
                var urlToBeLoaded = that.getFancyBoxId(currentTarget);
            });     
        }
    });         
}, // end openFirstFancyBox




openInAlreadyOpenedFancyBox: function (urlToBeLoaded) {
    var that = this;

    $.fancybox.showLoading(); // show loading icon
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlToBeLoaded,
        success : function(content, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $.fancybox.hideLoading();                        
            jQuery(".fancybox-inner").html(content);
            $.fancybox.update();
        },
        error : function(xhr, status) {
            $.fancybox.hideLoading();
            return false;
        }
    });
},

closeFancyBox: function () {
    this.fancyboxIsOpen = false;
    $.fancybox.close();
},

getFancyBoxId: function (currentTarget) {
    var id = currentTarget.attr("href");  
    return id;        
},
```

The important stuff is `jQuery(".fancybox-inner").html(content);` to replace the content of the current fancybox with the new content, and optionally `$.fancybox.update();` to resize the window according to the new content.

Answer (score 2):

in case if you are not using iframe. You can try following

```
jQuery.fancybox({'content' : html});
```

Answer (score 2):

For fancybox 3, come up with this solution:

```
$(`.foo`).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const self = $(this);

    $.fancybox.open({
        type: 'ajax',
        src: self.attr('href'),
        opts: {
            afterShow: function(instance, current) {
                $('.bar').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    instance.showLoading(current);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: $(this).attr('href'),
                        success: function(content) {
                            instance.hideLoading(current);
                            instance.setContent(current, content);
                            instance.update();
                        }
                    });

                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```